# Design Sql Tables with common columns

Tags: sql

I have 5 tables that have the same structure and same columns: **id, name, description**. So I wonder what is the best way to design or to avoid having 5 tables that have the same columns:

1. Create a category table that will include my three common
   columns and another column "enum" that will differentiate my categories
   ex (city, country, continent, etc.)
2. Create a category table that will include my three common
   columns and create the other five tables that will just include an
   id.

Note that I would have an assocation table that should include the id of cities, id countries, id continents, etc. so i can display them into a report

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Opinion: First option.  Seems more growth capacity via data than structure changes.

Comment: The column names are not important, just the data in the columns. If City description, country description and continent description are different information then you are already doing this the right way. The only time you would aim to reduce this data would be if you were repeating information but for the titles of the data it's fine.

Comment: So for my mapping table called map_tables it will contain only one column "category_id" ? how i can differentiate the different object (country, city) ? i should get them based on the enum column in my category table ?  If i choose the second option i can have country_id, city_id, etc. no ?

Comment: none of this. Taking the example of countries etc: You have three tables, city{id, countryid,continentId, name, etc}, country{id, continentId, name,etc} and continent{id, name, etc}. The inheritance is done through the ids matching a city.countryId to a country.id and so forth. Its mutually exclusive because you can add a field to city without having to add it to county and continent also, and vice versa. I think you are getting hung up on the titles of your fields. These are not hugely important.

Answer (score 0):

The column names are not important, just the data in the columns. If City description, country description and continent description are different information then you are already doing this the right way. The only time you would aim to reduce this data would be if you were repeating information but for the titles of the data it's fine.

In fact. You are doing this correctly. Country will have different values from city for every field mentioned. Id is just an id, every table should have one. Name and description wont be the same across country and city.

Also, this way if you want a countrys name you dont have to go through every country, continent and city. You only have 192 or so entries to go through. If you had all of that in one massive table you would have to use it for everything and go through every result every time you want data. You would also have to distinguish between cities, countries and continents in some other way than the separate tables.

Eg:

method 1, with 5 tables:

```
   SELECT * FROM country
```

does the same as

method 2, 1 table:

```
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE enumvalue = 'country';
```

Comment: I dont need to go through all the continent and city to get the Country, since i will have an index for the "enum" column

Comment: you will still have to go through the table to select which ones match your enum. The way you already have it is the best way. If you do have an enum, dont make it your index. You want a unique index(PK) for each table

Comment: I mean, you could dump them all into one table, but separate tables for separate entities is generally the accepted norm. It also makes things tidy and easier to work with

Comment: You are right, so i will go with my second option then. So if i create another table, i will just add it separately, add an id to it and then connect it to the category table

Comment: Ye that should work. A good rule is: A table for each entity, a table for each relationship

Comment: Right, in fact all the ids if the different 5 or 10 tables  and so should be included in my category table and each time i should insert an entity i should make sure that the id doesn't exist in the other tables !

Comment: You dont need a category table. The tables are your categories. If two are related as a many to many, you make a table with a primary key id and a foreign key id for each of the two related tables. If its a one to many relationship you simply add a foreign key id to the "many" table which represents the "one"s primary key

Comment: mm that means i will have the same columns in all the other tables ? that's the goal of my first post : avoid having the same columns in different tables and put the commun columns in one table like category : inheritance with mutual exclusion

Comment: if that is the case you are asking how to convert a 3nf database into a complete mess...and remove inheritance. If you really want to do it you could just add another two nullable ids to the single table to denote the country and continent ids that refer to an id in the same table.Also add your enum or a varchar to denote type. Please dont do this to your database.

Answer (score 0):

The decision on how many tables to have under these circumstances simply depends.

The most important factor is whether the five things are independent entities or whether they are related.  A simple way to understand this is by understanding foreign key relationships:  Will other tables have a column that could refer to any of the five (say "geoid")?  Or will other tables have a column that generally refers to one of the five ("cityid", "countryid")?  The ability to define helpful foreign key constraints often drives the table structure.

There are other considerations.  If your data is at the geographic level, then it might represent hierarchies . . . cities are in countries, countries are on continents.  Some databases (such as MySQL) do not support hierarchical queries at all.  Under these circumstances, you might consider denormalizing the data for querying purposes.

Other considerations can also come into play.  If your application is going to be internationalized, then having all the reference tables in a single place is handy -- for providing cultural-specific information (language, currency symbol, and so on).  One way of handling this situation is to put all such references in a single table (and perhaps using more sophisticated foreign key relationships).

Comment: Country and city it's just an example, i can have books and pencils as well, so there's no hierarchies. So what's you suggestion then ? use the second option and create separate tables with only an id and all the values of those ids in the different tables will be included in the category table ? Maybe this option will be good for me so i can easly use a map table and get id's from differents table : country_id, city_id, book_id, pencil_id, etc. What do you think ?

Comment: @user708683 . . . Separate tables for different entities are a natural way to organize data in a database.  Note that the entities that you describe have different attributes . . . books have ISBN numbers, pencils have lead hardness, and so on.

Comment: But i will still need a category table or a commun table that will contain my commun columns like name, description and add only the different attributes specific for each entity

Answer (score 0):

If you have tables representing city, country and continent, and they all have exactly the same fields, you have a fundamental problem.  In real life, every city is in a country and every country is in at least one continent (more or less) but your data structure does not reflect that.  Your city table should look something like this:

```
 id (primary key)
 countryId (foreign key to country)
 name
 other fields
```

You'll need a similar relationship between countries and continents.  However, before you do so, you have to decide what to do about countries like Russia which is in two continents and Palau which isn't really in any.

You may also want to have a provinceStateTerritory table to help you sort out the 38 places in the United States named Springfield.  Or, you may want to handle that situation differently.

Comment: I got that, but like i said, the country and city is just an example. Let's say i have 30 entities having the same columns (id,name, description) and instead of having id,name,description in each table, i want to have it a commun table and then only have the id in each table. Reading you guys, the best approach is to have id,name,description in each table.